# Spring Boot file storage architecture that accessible from multi project

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have two separate project Admin and User using spring boot, spring mvc. I would store the files especially images. The file will be uploaded via Admin project or User project. What I would like to ask the question is that how should i store the file(images) use in both project.

In my understanding the file(image) should be store under resources(configured in spring mvc) directory to show in the html. So there will be two resources for each separate project.

Comment: No. Uploaded files are not static resources of the projects. They are dynamic data provided by the users of your app. So you treat them as data, by storing them in some database (which could be a real database shared by the two apps, or a file system shared by the two apps, or an external storage service used by the two apps).

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet I see the uploaded files are the dynamic data. Then I will store them in the file system. But can I configure the file-system as the static resources in spring mvc?

Comment: If you want to, yes, you can. But you'd typically want to prevent anyone to access images of other users, wouldn't you? So you'd better have a controller checking access to the images before serving them. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content

Comment: Thanks I see, Noted.